# Statistical test to infer if brand preference depends on income

Tags: statistics

For the data in image can anyone please suggest the right statistical test. **Want to test if brand preference depends on income level.**

The percentages adds upto 100% row wise meaning the values in a row are percentage share of different brands in total purchase amount of an income group.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need to know the sample size as well and multiply it back out from the percentages into frequency counts.

After that, my suggestion is you do a Chi Square Test for independence, since you have two categorical variables.

Either that or you can do an ANOVA (you technically have 3 variables: something for the percentage like a yes/no, brand, and income) , but you'll have to structure you data differently to do that and you will need the sample detail. You'll also need to convert your categorical variables into dummy variables.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I think chisq won't be applicable as data is not about frequencies but sales amount. The percentages are sales share of different brands in an income group. I will explore anova.